# Will a shutdown Android phone wake me up (like feature phones do)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, alarm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the alarm work when my phone is turned off?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/does-the-alarm-work-when-my-phone-is-turned-off)

I have three devices with Android and I just wanna one of them alarming when turned off.

I turn off my devices to do not receive any alert type from sync, apps, calling, sms etc. and also to do not waste battery charge.

I know I could just switch devices to airplane or silent mode and connect them to power, but I would like to know just how to use alarm when device is turned off... I miss that feature from my old dumbphones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with standard Android.

To sum it up: The alarm on feature phones is triggered by a hardware component (most probably the real time clock, called RTC). Subsequently this component wakes the CPU  by raising an interrupt and the CPU runs a dedicated program (interrupt service routine,ISR) which just plays the alarm tune. It's all very low level probably.

Android is much more high-level than this and does not support this out of the box (most probably). Any handset manufacturer may of course implement this feature using the same methods as with feature phones, but this is not belonging to the Android OS strictly speaking then. There are too much layers involved to do this without starting up Android.

Note: Android allows full device encryption also; how should this work when nothing is accessible without your passphrase? Android couldn't even start.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to sound the alarm when the device turns off. This is a limitation in the Android operating system.

If you have a certain Samsung device, you use the [NoMoarPowah](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.nomoarpowah) app, but this only supports a very small number of devices.

Comment: Yes, I have a Samsung device, but after installed the app it does not open with a popup informing resolution issue appeared (device must have 800x480 resolution). Also on description of it, it informs that mobile must be rooted...

Comment: Yes, I assumed your's was - although I shouldn't have (sorry). It has to be the Specific (Rooted) Samsung devices in the description. If it doesn't work with your device, then there is no way to do what you're asking sorry.

Answer (score 2):

My default answer again: It could be done using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), the big automation tool. *Tasker* can react on the Shutdown event:

**Context:** Event → Device Shutdown
**Task:** (Chose your desired alarm: Play a sound, send a SMS/Mail, ...)

Comment: Through Alternativeto.net, I found AutomateIt (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiQXV0b21hdGVJdC5tYWluUGFja2FnZSJd) that has a free option (with ads)... Trying

Comment: There is a free 7-day trial of *Tasker* available on their homepage as well. You can export your config, and remove/re-install the app on the 7th day for another 7-day-trial, according to the dev. But if *AutomateIt* solves your problem as well -- why not :)

Comment: This wouldn't work though, would it? This would only play a tone when the phone is turned off, not sound a scheduled alarm while the device is off.

Comment: My tests failed with AutomateIt. I'll try 7-day trial of Tasker. I thinking in the same way @TheAndroNerd...

Comment: Oops -- did I misinterprete your question? I thought you wanted to be alarmed when the device is *going to be* shut down -- not when it already is switched-off. If you're looking for the latter: Sorry pal, no way.