# Alarm is working even when the phone is powered off

Tags: security, 4.3-jelly-bean, alarm, power-on

I just discovered that if I set the alarm clock and then power off the phone (by holding the power button and then selecting "Power Off") the alarm will still go off when the time comes.

Is this expected behavior? It makes me feel like "power off" doesn't actually power off the phone.

I have a Huawei Y530-U051 running android 4.3.

Comment: Ugh? That would indeed be something new *with Android devices*. Old "dumbphones" had such a feature alright; but for Android (and other smartphones) it was always said "off is off". It would be technically possible, but I've never heard it was implemented. When the alarm sounds: had the phone restarted then? Or how can you control the alarm (e.g. snooze it, or put it off) if not?

Comment: @Eric you have one feature, what most of other android phones are lacking..this is totally unexpected behaviour in android..but hey i think its only in huawei phones so just enjoy with tht feature..

Comment: Related: [Does the alarm work when my phone is turned off?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4206/44325)

Comment: Don't spread misinformation! Not many Android phones do it, not Samsung and especially not Apple and iOS! But you will find the feature in most Chinese phones flooding the market with cheap Android smartphones. I have it in my Alcatel Onetouch Idol 3 running Lollipop 5.0.2 and it's an awesome feature!

Answer (score 11):

That is expected behavior. It allows you to turn the phone off if you need to ensure the battery doesn't drain (or whatever other use-case you can think up) and still have a usable alarm clock. It's not new, many Android devices do something similar, and every iPhone since the first-generation models also had that feature. I can also recall an old Nokia 3310 I had back in the early 2000's which did the exact same thing.

Turning the phone off does shut down the OS, so don't worry about that. Android supports the setting of "[hardware alarms](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1942)", which let the phone boot automatically at a predetermined time. Not every manufacturer included support for them, but yours obviously did.

Edit: The hardware alarm feature has been deprecated by Apple and isn't useable any longer.

Comment: most of us expect manufacturers or Android OS to set this option for making the device ring alarm even if its is turned off..this is badly missing in most smartphones unlike the good old Nokia phones..

Comment: :( seems the Oneplus Two phone doesn't come with this feature. My old Nexus 4 phone did, it saved me once when the battery died and it came back to life just long enough to sound the alarm.

Comment: @lucky it isn't up to Android alone; Android supports hardware alarms, but they must be included in the HW design and implemented.

Answer (score 1):

On my Redmi 7, my Clock app Settings -> Additional alarm settings, has a feature Shutdown alarm, which I can disable so that the alarm does not go off after the device is powered off. It's a very useful feature, but I wish I had discovered it before my alarm woke me unnecessarily at 5:25AM, and not after. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When the phone is turned off, it doesn’t mean that it is completely off. It is like in a sleep mode and the processor is still running a lower level system which does tasks like running the clock to keep the time correct, continuously monitoring the power button to know when to turn the phone on. As the clock is running and it is the alarm time , so the processor sends a signal to turn the phone on. Then the phone is turned on and the alarm rings.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped my Android Galaxy S22 plus, and the screen broke. It's just a black screen, and unusable now. However, even though I never charged it again, the alarm still goes off 3 times every morning. I have to hit the off button to turn it off or it will go on forever. I have tried to get into my AT&T account from another phone to disable this phone, but even after I verify who I am via my email, it again asks me to verify who I am via a code sent to my phone, and guess what? I can't see the code on the broken, black screen of that phone. I can't wait until my new phone arrives from the refurbishing company and I can send the broken one to them. Unfortunately,the neverending alarm will be the mail carrier's dilemma, then.so although I don't have a solution, I can confirm that even after the battery should be long dead, the alarm will go on. Apparently forever.

Comment: I wonder how this is possible.  I'm guessing the battery still has some charge, but not enough to boot the device.

Answer (score -1):

Remember when you turned on your old mobile phone and you didn't have to set up the time every day again because the phone remembered what time it is?

It's not something of new, it's just that the phone starts a minute before the timer hits the alarm and it's build in because the phone requires at least 4 hours of recharge to last 10 hours of sleep in order to wake you up and not all customers have the possibility of having the wall charger or having the phone charged in their own room with a laptop in their own room.

However you can turn it off by clicking the small check button on the bottom of the screen when you turn the mobile off, so to say it, all phones hibernate on some level in case you don't happen to pull the battery off every time you want the phone closed completely.